# Codeigniter 4 How to call a controller method in a view?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter-4

I have a function with named pr in BaseController. I can access this function in my controllers but i want use this function in views too. Is there is a way ?

[image: Controller File]

[image: view file]

Edit:
this is how i try to use pr in view.

```
 <div class="col-md-9">
<?php

$this->pr("11", 22);
```

and my pr function is ;

```
 public function pr($array, $die = "", $type = "")
    {
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", '-1');
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", '-1');
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", '-1');

        echo "<pre>";
        if (!$type) print_r($array);
        else var_dump($array);
        echo "</pre>";
        if ($die) die();
    }
```

Comment: please do not tag photo or screenshot either copy and paste the overall code.

Comment: `pr` is a method in your \App\Controller\Home class. So it should be `\App\Controller\Home::pr()`. Instead, you were calling `CodeIgniter\View\View::pr()`. However you called pr in your view (you're not showing your view code), you're not doing it right. Please show more of the pr method code and your view.

Comment: @KoalaYeung added my view and pr codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `pr` wrong:

1. `pr` is a method in your \App\Controller\Home class. So it should be \App\Controller\Home::pr(). Instead, you were calling \CodeIgniter\View\View::pr().
2. Views are probably rendered in to some \CodeIgniter\View\View class instance, hence calling `$this` in a view results in calling `\CodeIgniter\View\View::pr()`. That's why a `$this->pr()` call isn't working as you expected.
3. Your `Home::pr()` is an ordinary method, which can only be called within the instance (i.e. through `$this` inside an instance). Your view do not have access to it.
4. It seems your `pr` is not doing anything specific to the Controller instance (i.e. not using `$this` inside), you can simply rewrite it as a public static method, which can easily be called in your view.

So, this is probably useful for you.

Controller:

```php
namespace App\Controllers;

...

class Home {

    ...

    public static function pr($array, $die = "", $type = "")
    {
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", '-1');
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", '-1');
        ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", '-1');

        echo "<pre>";
        if (!$type) print_r($array);
        else var_dump($array);
        echo "</pre>";
        if ($die) die();
    }

    ...

}
```

View:

```php
 <div class="col-md-9">
 <?php \App\Controllers\Home::pr("11", 22); ?>
```